# Enabling a Button after a Method

Tags: javascript, function, button

I am having problems with my javascript. 
I need a button to "enable" after uploading an image, but what happens is it restarts the function. After uploading the image, the button that is disabled will be "enabled" but in just a blink of an eye, it will be disabled again. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Nina, you will need to give more detail as to what you are doing.  Where are you uploading the image? What server technology are you using?  What does the upload page look like (show the html, javascript, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Keep the display button initially to none as follows:

```
    <asp:Button id="btnID" runat="server" style="display:none">
```

After uploading within the upload button click event change the button display to block :

```
      UploadBtn_Click()
      {
               //perform Upload logic here
                 btnID.attributes.add("style","display:block");
       }
```

Hope this helps..